# Send Direct Message Using Instagram Official API

Tags: instagram, messaging, instagram-api

I have been working with Facebook API and there documentation is awesome. Now i need to use the Instagram API and there documentation is not developer friendly, I want to use the Direct message functionality using Instagram API and i am unable to find that how to do it? as i can't see it in there documentation and I have been doing research for hours but unable to find any best possible resource.
I don't even know that are they providing the "Direct message" functionality or not? After my all research i have come to know about "Instagram Private API" which provides direct messaging functionality but i don't know that are they officially using there API's for messaging. I am sure they are using a Hack for that but i don't know that for how much time hack lasts long.

Any One who can guide me would be great.
I appreciate for your time and consideration.
Please do let me know about your concerns on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey ! Same for me, did you find something?

Comment: Hi there,
Sorry for the late Reply!
I did not find any solution regarding this but what i found is that there is an Private API named as Instagram Private API which is not official.
They provide the functionality for sending direct messages.
But most of the people did not recommend that because of un-official resource, So no one knows when it banns or when they start to Charge you when your business is working on that.
Hope it helps.

Comment: yes and it works :) thanks

Comment: Your Welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

**A Bit Late To Answer (Aug, 2022)**

I have successfully cracked it by myself, after doing a lot of research on google over this topic. You can use the mentioned deep link to open Instagram Direct with some text to share from your application,

```
instagram://sharesheet?text={AnyTextOrLinkToShare}
```

Moreover, the below code should work on iOS to launch Instagram Direct (Messenger) from your app with some content

```
if let url = URL(string: "instagram://sharesheet?text=https://google.com/") {
   UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Not sure, why did they hide this information from their official documentation but now who cares, I have achieved it with the continuous efforts of 16-18 hrs! :)